# Unable to catch SocketException in flutter http package

Tags: android, flutter, http, dart

I am unable to catch `SocketException` in flutter `http` package.

```
Future<User> getUserDetail(String token) async {
  try {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(userURL), headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    });
    return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    // this catch does not catch SocketException
  } catch(e) {
    print('Error catched: $e');
  }
}
```

I face this problem when the emulator is in airplane mode or the local server is not reachable. Otherwise every things work fine.
So my question is this, that why I am not able to catch those exceptions?

These images show the problem I face.
[image]
[image]

My flutter version is 2.0.5 and there is no issue in `flutter doctor` and I also added internet permission and `cleartextTraffic = "true"` in `AndroidManifiest.xml`.

Comment: @pskink - you mean this issue is because of my flutter version ?

Comment: same problem if i turn device to airplane mode.

Comment: SocketException like the image I attached above.

Comment: Now I am upgrading flutter to 2.2.0. let's see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Bro, I get that app crash in the image above if I turn the emulator to airplane mode. otherwise it works fine and i get the response (with my code or your code). my problem is in airplane mode or when the server is not reachable.

Comment: Yeah I should but I don't, that is why I created this question. I have the global catch block and it should catches any exception but it doesn't and the app crashes. that's my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating flutter `2.0.5` to `2.2.0` solved the problem.